# Warp and response types and trait objects?

Tags: rust, traits, rust-warp

I have a Warp rejection handler, I'm using it like this,

```
.recover(handle_rejection)
```

It's declared like this,

```rust
pub async fn handle_rejection(err: Rejection) -> Result<impl warp::reply::Reply, Infallible> {
```

If both sides of the `if` statement are the same type,

```rust
if let Some(e) = err.find::<crate::api::error::UserError>() {
  Ok(warp::reply::with_status(
    warp::reply::reply(),
    warp::http::StatusCode::NOT_FOUND,
  ))
}
else {
  Ok(warp::reply::with_status(
    warp::reply::reply(),
    warp::http::StatusCode::NOT_FOUND,
  ))
}
```

Everything works fine, but if change one of those sides to be,

```rust
Ok(e.into_response())
```

It's no longer ok, I get this error on compilation,

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/api.rs:22:8
   |
22 |                   Ok(warp::reply::with_status(
   |  ____________________^
23 | |                     warp::reply::reply(),
24 | |                     warp::http::StatusCode::NOT_FOUND,
25 | |                 ))
   | |_________________^ expected struct `Response`, found struct `WithStatus`
   |
```

I don't understand that though, because that side didn't change, this should still satisfy `impl warp::reply::Reply`, what's the problem here?

I've tried different permutation of casting to the trait object explicitly like `as warp::reply::Reply` and as `&dyn warp::reply::Reply` but they don't work either.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `impl Trait` is just a shorthand for some concrete
type that implements `Trait`. So this:

```rust
fn foo() -> impl Bar {}
```

is the same as this:

```rust
fn foo() -> SomeConcreteTypeImplementingBar {}
```

Where `SomeConcreteTypeImplementingBar` is determined automatically (Thanks @Jmb for the correction).

Although not correct, it might help to think of it as this:

```rust
fn foo<B: Bar>() -> B
```

This is **not** the same, because the user specifies the type `B`, not the function, but it might be helpful for demonstration purposes. The real purpose of `impl` is to say "I'm going to return *some* type that implements `Bar`, but I won't tell you what that type is".

Eventually, Rust has to figure out the concrete type that is being returned. However, consider the following:

```rust
trait Bar {}

struct One;
impl Bar for One {}

struct Two;
impl Bar for Two {}

fn foo() -> impl Bar {
    if some_condition {
        One
    } else {
        Two
    }
}
```

What concrete type should the compiler choose? Well, it could either be `One` or `Two`, depending on what `some_condition` is! In this case, the compiler doesn't know which type to choose, so it throws an error.

This is the same error that you're getting. The two arms of your if statement are returning different types, so the compiler is throwing an error, telling you that it expects the type of both arms of the if statement to be either struct `Response` or struct `WithStatus`. To solve this issue, you can:

- Create a new type that implements `Reply` that encapsulates both cases, then just return that type
- Rework your function to only use one type. The above option is one case of this, but you could also use a `warp` built-in type
- `Box` your return value. The resulting code would look like this:

```rust
pub async fn handle_rejection(err: Rejection) -> Result<Box<dyn warp::reply::Reply>, Infallible> {
```

```rust
if let Some(e) = err.find::<crate::api::error::UserError>() {
    Ok(Box::new(e.into_response()))
} else {
    Ok(Box::new(warp::reply::with_status(
        warp::reply::reply(),
        warp::http::StatusCode::NOT_FOUND,
    )))
}
```

Comment: Note that the same error would be thrown for any if or match statement whose arms have different types

Comment: `fn foo() -> impl Bar` is _not_ the same as `fn foo<B: Bar>() -> B` _at all_! In the second case the type `B` is chosen by the caller, whereas in the first case the return type is chosen by the function being implemented. `fn foo() -> impl Bar` is equivalent to `fn foo() -> SomeConcreteTypeImplementingBar` where `SomeConcreteTypeImplementingBar` is determined automatically.

Comment: @Jmb you are correct, I'm sorry for the disinformation. I thought a generic parameter would be easier to understand, even though it, as you point out, is not the same as `impl`. I've edited the answer to clarify. Does it look good to you?